# concatenate image before and after existing video

Tags: ffmpeg

I am using `ffmpeg` to generate video slideshow. and want to add one image before and after the video file generated to cocatenate as intro-outro slide.

This is the code I'm trying to run

```
ffmpeg -y -f concat -loop 1 -t 5 -i /path_to/intro.png -i /path_to/video.mp4 -loop 1 -t 5 -i /path_to/outro.png /path_to/output.mp4
```

**But this is giving error as**

```
Line 1: unknown keyword '�PNG'
/path_to/intro.png: Invalid data found when processing input
```

The image is generated using base64 code as

```
$outro_data = 'data:image/png;base64,iVBOPgAAAAUdklEQVR4nO3d+ZdU5ZnA8fwZBqNA...';
list($type, $outro_data) = explode(';', $outro_data);
list(, $outro_data)      = explode(',', $outro_data);
file_put_contents($output_outro_image_path, base64_decode($outro_data));
```

Sample image:
[image]

> Edit 2

error log

```
ffmpeg version 3.2.2-2~16.04.york0 Copyright (c) 2000-2016 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 5.4.1 (Ubuntu 5.4.1-4ubuntu1~16.04.york1) 20161202
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version='2~16.04.york0' --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu --enable-gpl --disable-stripping --enable-avresample --enable-avisynth --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libebur128 --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librubberband --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-omx --enable-openal --enable-opengl --enable-sdl2 --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libiec61883 --enable-chromaprint --enable-frei0r --enable-libopencv --enable-libx264 --enable-shared
  libavutil      55. 34.100 / 55. 34.100
  libavcodec     57. 64.101 / 57. 64.101
  libavformat    57. 56.100 / 57. 56.100
  libavdevice    57.  1.100 / 57.  1.100
  libavfilter     6. 65.100 /  6. 65.100
  libavresample   3.  1.  0 /  3.  1.  0
  libswscale      4.  2.100 /  4.  2.100
  libswresample   2.  3.100 /  2.  3.100
  libpostproc    54.  1.100 / 54.  1.100
Input #0, png_pipe, from 'in1.png':
  Duration: N/A, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0:0: Video: png, rgba(pc), 640x400 [SAR 2835:2835 DAR 8:5], 25 fps, 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc
Input #1, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'out_60.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf56.40.101
  Duration: 00:00:25.00, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 22 kb/s
    Stream #1:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 640x400 [SAR 1:1 DAR 8:5], 16 kb/s, 60 fps, 60 tbr, 15360 tbn, 120 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
Input #2, png_pipe, from 'in4.png':
  Duration: N/A, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #2:0: Video: png, rgba(pc), 640x400 [SAR 2835:2835 DAR 8:5], 25 fps, 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc
Input #3, lavfi, from 'anullsrc':
  Duration: N/A, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 705 kb/s
    Stream #3:0: Audio: pcm_u8, 44100 Hz, stereo, u8, 705 kb/s
Stream specifier ':a' in filtergraph description [0]crop=iw:400[v0];[v0][3][1:v][1:a][2][3]concat=n=3:v=1:a=1[vv][a];[vv]format=yuv420p[v] matches no streams.
```

**Command executing**

```
ffmpeg -loop 1 -t 5 -i in1.png -i 1514273842_1106877394.mp4 -loop 1 -t 5 -i in4.png -f lavfi -t 5 -i anullsrc -filter_complex "[0]crop=iw:400[v0];[v0][3][1:v][1:a][2][3]concat=n=3:v=1:a=1[vv][a];[vv]format=yuv420p[v]" -map "[v]" -map "[a]" output_concat.mp4
```

Comment: please check, have added sample image produced by base64

Answer (score 0):

## concat filter

You can use the [concat filter](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#concat):

```
ffmpeg -loop 1 -t 5 -i intro.png -i video.mp4 -loop 1 -t 5 -i outro.png -f lavfi -t 5 -i anullsrc -filter_complex "[0][3][1:v][1:a][2][3]concat=n=3:v=1:a=1[vv][a];[vv]format=yuv420p[v]" -map "[v]" -map "[a]" output.mp4
```

- Advantage is that you can do everything in one line, and you can match parameters of each input using various filters.
- Disadvantage is that you re-encode `video.mp4`.

## concat demuxer

Alternatively, make videos from images matching parameters of `video.mp4`. You didn't provide any details of `video.mp4` so I can't give a turnkey example. Then use the [concat demuxer](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#concat):

```
ffmpeg -f concat -i input.txt -c copy output.mp4
```

`input.txt` contains:

```
file 'intro.mp4'
file 'video.mp4'
file 'outro.mp4'
```

- Advantage is that `video.mp4` is stream copied and not re-encoded and the whole process may be faster than the concat filter method.
- Disadvantage is that it is more prone to user error if input file parameters do not match.

Comment: I tried and it gives error `Input link in1:v0 parameters (size 640x480, SAR 1:1) do not match the corresponding output link in0:v0 parameters (640x400, SAR 1:1)`

Comment: @AnujTBE Add the scale, pad, crop, and/or setsar filters to make the inputs the same width and height and SAR (lots of examples here on SO). If you included the complete ffmpeg console output along with the command in your question I could have provided an example for you to simply copy and paste, but I was only able to give you a generic example that you must adapt to fit your exact needs. So, assuming you're using the concat filter, use something like `"[0]crop=iw:400[v0];[v0][3][1:v][1:a][2][3]concat=n=3:v=1:a=1[vv][a];[vv]format=yuv420p[v]"`

Comment: again it is giving error `Stream specifier ':a' in filtergraph description [0]crop=iw:400[v0];[v0][3][1:v][1:a][2][3]concat=n=3:v=1:a=1[vv][a];[vv]format=yuv420p[v] matches no streams.`. See `Edit 2` for full error log

Comment: @AnujTBE I need to see the full command that made that error log.

Comment: @AnujTBE `1514273842_1106877394.mp4` has no audio so you can eliminate all audio related options. Also, your inputs all have the same width, height, and SAR, so you can eliminate crop: `ffmpeg -loop 1 -t 5 -i in1.png -i 1514273842_1106877394.mp4 -loop 1 -t 5 -i in4.png -filter_complex "[0][1][2]concat=n=3:v=1:a=0,format=yuv420p" output_concat.mp4`

Answer (score 0):

```
{
    "-loop",
    " 1",
    "-framerate",
    "24",
    "-t",
    "5",
    "-i",
    imag1.jpg,
    "-i",
    video.mp4,
    "-loop",
    " 1",
    "-framerate",
    "24",
    "-t",
    "5",
    "-i",
    image2.jpg,
    "-f",
    "lavfi",
    "-t",
    "0.1",
    "-i",
    "anullsrc=channel_layout=stereo:sample_rate=44100",
    "-filter_complex",
    "[2]scale=480:360,setsar=1[im];[1]scale=480:360,setsar=1[vid];[0]scale=480:360,setsar=1[im]; [im][3][vid][1][im][3] concat=n=3:v=1:a=1",
    filePath
};
```

Comment: Please can you explain how your code helps answer the question.